# MPMoviePlayerViewController, ARC и EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios

Пишу первое свое мобильное приложение для iOS.
В приложении хочу реализовать возможность проигрывания видео с удаленного сервера.

В .h файле:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController *videoPl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *videoURL;
```

В .m файле:

```
@synthesize videoPl, videoURL;

....

// Указываю путь до видео-файла
self.videoURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@v%d.MP4", path, cellIndex];

// Инициализирую видео-проигрыватель 
self.videoPl = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoURL]];
[videoPl.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
[videoPl.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];

// Показываю его
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:videoPl];
```

При открытии первого ролика - видео проигрывается нормально. Занятая память при этом растет до 50-70Мб (в зависимости от размера видео). Когда пытаюсь открыть второй файл, то либо сразу либо через какое-то время приложение крашится:

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2000000c)`

Пробовал дожидаться окончания буферизации и проигрывания, пробовал strong менять на weak, искал в интернете...

Подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку - что необходимо сделать чтобы избежать крашей?

Может быть у Вас есть проверенная рабочая реализация?

Answer (score 1):

После долгих поисков, нашел решение:

По событию `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` (пользователь нажал Done при воспроизведении) необходимо остановить проигрыватель:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieEventFullscreenHandler:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (IBAction) movieEventFullscreenHandler:(NSNotification*)notification
{
[self.player.moviePlayer stop];
[self.player.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:NO];
}
```